# How to GET Parse' Object without createdAt, updatedAt or objectId in REST API

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I'm getting trouble with a heavy load of data from Parse that a GET returned. The data contains many objects with 2 fields that I need (include objectId). Now I want to strip down the createdAt and updatedAt fields to save bandwidth but could not find any clue for this.

Does anyone face this? How can I do to get a compact data that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own function in cloud code that return only fields you want. But is not possible to remove the createdAt, updatedAt and objectId fields from class.

> The objectId, createdAt, updatedAt fields cannot be edited (these are set automatically)

Source: https://www.parse.com/docs/data#data-browser

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. That would make the query on the cloud side and not on your side. The return (of your choice) would then be much smaller

Comment: I see function calls slower than normal request, isn't it?